# Mix audio from speaker and microphone in android

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I was trying to record the sound from the mic. The sound is sampled against the tone running in background.

To make it clear i want to run a tone in background and when i make some noise from microphone this should be mixed with the background tone that is already playing.

The final output should be a mix of the tone played and the signals from the microphone which is the noise. How can i achieve this.

I was referring to the post [Android : recording audio using audiorecord class play as fast forwarded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862662/android-recording-audio-using-audiorecord-class-play-as-fast-forwarded) in stackoverflow to record data from microphone. But i need to record the background tone as well as the microphone input.

```
public class StartRecording {

    private int samplePerSec = 8000;

    public void Start(){
        stopRecording.setEnabled(true);
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(samplePerSec, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, this.samplePerSec, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize * 10);
        audioRecorder.startRecording();
        isRecording = true;


        while (isRecording && audioRecorder.getRecordingState() == AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING)
        {
            short recordedData[] = new short[bufferSize];
            audioRecorder.read(recordedData, 0, recordedData.length);      // Reading from the audiorecorder
            byte[] bData = shortTobyte(recordedData);
        }
    }
}

private byte[] shortTobyte(short[] recordedData) {
    int tempBuff = recordedData.length;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[tempBuff * 10];

    for (int i = 0; i < tempBuff; i++) {
        bytes[i * 2] = (byte) (recordedData[i] & 0x00FF);
        bytes[(i * 2) + 1] = (byte) (recordedData[i] >> 8);
        recordedData[i] = 0;
    }
    return bytes;

}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: did to achive that ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AudioTrack and AudioRecord simulteanously.
Then all buffers from AudioRecord must be mixed to your tone (there are some algo on google for mixing 2 audio signals) and written in the AudioTrack.

You will have latency and some problems with echo if you don't use a headset.